# Cant post to api. 400 fetch error (React)

Tags: reactjs, database, post

I have an issue when i am trying to post to my API (Net6.0) because i get the error of 400 fetch, i have tried different things that i have found on here but i cant seem to fix it.

Here is my code:

my function:

```
const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
const [description, setDescription] = useState('');
const [link, setLink] = useState('');

const handleSubmit =(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const post = { title, description, link };
    fetch('https://localhost:7018/api/Posts', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify(post)
    }).then(() => {
        console.log('new post added');
        // GoBack()
    })
}
```

and my return:

```
<div className="create">
    
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>Titel</label>
        <input 
            type="text"
            required
            value={title}
            onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
        />
        <label>Description</label>
        <textarea
            required
            value={description}
            onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}
        ></textarea>
        <label>Link</label>
        <input 
            type="text"
            required
            value={link}
            onChange={(e) => setLink(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button>Skapa Inlägg</button>
        <p>{ title }</p>
        <p>{ description }</p>
        <p>{ link }</p>
    </form>
</div>
```

here is the error code i get
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHwTn.png

Comment: You need to find out why the server is returning an error 400. This is probably a backend problem, not a frontend problem, and has nothing to do with React. Also you have `https` on localhost - do you have certified localhost?

Comment: What do you mean with a ceritfied localhost? And also i can post and reach all my endpoints from swagger, but its only the post method in react thats the issue thats why i thought it was a front end issue. (I am a newbie in programming)

Comment: Do you have any error message from server? Try to add `.catch(err => console.log(err))` after your `.then` or inspect request in your devtools (click on request as is on your screenshot > view at "preview"/"response")

Comment: Thanks for the comment i got the error "user field is required".